Break basic blocks in llvm over function calls
I have a C function that invokes bar()
void foo(int x) {
    bar(x);
    bar(x + 1);
}

Its LLVM IR looks like
    define dso_local void @foo(i32 noundef %0) #0 {
entry:
      %2 = alloca i32, align 4
      store i32 %0, i32* %2, align 4
      %3 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
      call void @bar(i32 noundef %3)
      %4 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
      %5 = add nsw i32 %4, 1
      call void @bar(i32 noundef %5)
      ret void
    }

One can observe that the whole function consists of a single basic blocks, although the function calls actually break the control flow.
I would like to transform the function body so that it becomes
entry:
      %2 = alloca i32, align 4
      store i32 %0, i32* %2, align 4
      %3 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
      call void @bar(i32 noundef %3)

func_ret1:
      %4 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
      %5 = add nsw i32 %4, 1
      call void @bar(i32 noundef %5)

func_ret2:
      ret void

In this way, each basic blocks is a straight line code except its last instruction being a jump instruction, which is how existing llvm IR is composed of basicblocks. This can ease some program analysis tasks I am conducting. Is there a built-in llvm pass for this, or how would you safely implement this pass?
